# Get percentage in sql with multi join

Tags: php, sql

I have 3 tables, I want group query by series.title_name and I don't know how to do to get the percentage of episodes watched by the user.
What I am trying to do is to get all watched episodes in user_watched table multiply by 100 then divide by all episodes of the series in series table.

here is my tables:

**table series (all series are stored here)**

id | title_name | first_air_date | plot

**table episodes (all episodes are stored here)**

id | series_id | seasons_id | air_date

**table users_watched (all watched episodes are stored here)**

id | user_id | series_id | type_id(episode id) | type_name(episodes) | season_id

**Here is my code:**

```
SELECT name_table.*, uw.series_id, COUNT(ep.id) all_epi, COUNT(uw.series_id) watched,
       ROUND(COUNT(uw.series_id) *100 / COUNT(ep.id)) percentage
FROM series name_table
    LEFT JOIN users_watched uw ON uw.series_id = name_table.id
    LEFT JOIN episodes ep ON ep.id = uw.type_id
WHERE uw.type_name = 'episodes'
GROUP BY name_table.title_name
ORDER BY percentage DESC
```

**Result I get:**

```
array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#28 (39) { ["id"]=> string(1) "7" ["title_name"]=> string(15) "Game of Thrones" ["created_by"]=> string(26) "David Benioff, D. B. Weiss" ["first_air_date"]=> string(10) "2011-04-17" ["last_air_date"]=> NULL ["airs_day_ofweek"]=> string(6) "Sunday" ["airs_time"]=> string(8) "21:00:00" ["year_released"]=> NULL ["plot"]=> string(715) "Il y a très longtemps, à une époque oubliée, une force a détruit l'équilibre des saisons. Dans un pays où l'été peut durer plusieurs années et l'hiver toute une vie, des forces sinistres et surnaturelles se pressent aux portes du Royaume des Sept Couronnes. La confrérie de la Garde de Nuit, protégeant le Royaume de toute créature pouvant provenir d'au-delà du Mur protecteur, n'a plus les ressources nécessaires pour assurer la sécurité de tous. Après un été de dix années, un hiver rigoureux s'abat sur le Royaume avec la promesse d'un avenir des plus sombres. Pendant ce temps, complots et rivalités se jouent sur le continent pour s'emparer du Trône de fer, le symbole du pouvoir absolu." ["genre"]=> string(56) "Action & Adventure, Drame, Science-Fiction & Fantastique" ["homepage"]=> string(34) "http://www.hbo.com/game-of-thrones" ["tagline"]=> NULL ["poster"]=> string(31) "3iYNC7Iw6a65ed5GZz7KbInSHBd.jpg" ["background"]=> string(31) "mUkuc2wyV9dHLG0D0Loaw5pO2s8.jpg" ["episode_run_time"]=> string(2) "60" ["number_of_episodes"]=> string(2) "61" ["number_of_seasons"]=> string(1) "7" ["trailer"]=> NULL ["network"]=> string(3) "HBO" ["budget"]=> NULL ["earnings"]=> NULL ["box_office"]=> NULL ["tmdb_id"]=> string(4) "1399" ["thetvdb_id"]=> string(6) "121361" ["original_title"]=> string(15) "Game of Thrones" ["original_lang"]=> string(2) "en" ["origin_country"]=> string(2) "US" ["production_company"]=> string(62) "Home Box Office (HBO), Generator Entertainment, Television 360" ["production_country"]=> NULL ["certification"]=> NULL ["status"]=> string(16) "Returning Series" ["in_production"]=> string(1) "1" ["fully_scraped"]=> string(1) "1" ["creation_date"]=> string(19) "2017-03-12 14:17:17" ["update_date"]=> string(19) "2017-03-17 18:47:52" ["series_id"]=> string(1) "7" ["all_epi"]=> string(2) "74" ["watched"]=> string(2) "74" ["percentage"]=> string(3) "100" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#29 (39) { ["id"]=> string(3) "179" ["title_name"]=> string(13) "The Last Ship" ["created_by"]=> string(27) "Hank Steinberg, Steven Kane" ["first_air_date"]=> string(10) "2014-06-22" ["last_air_date"]=> NULL ["airs_day_ofweek"]=> string(6) "Sunday" ["airs_time"]=> string(8) "21:00:00" ["year_released"]=> NULL ["plot"]=> string(561) "Après avoir passé plusieurs mois en Arctique pour une mission top secrète, l'équipage de l'USS Nathan James, un destroyer de la NAVY, découvre avec horreur qu'une épidémie a décimé une majeure partie de la population terrestre. La Chine et l'Europe sont en guerre, tandis que le Gouvernement Américain n'est plus. Protégés par les océans, le commandant et les 200 âmes sous ses ordres font partie des derniers survivants de la planète. Une scientifique présente à bord doit absolument trouver un vaccin avant l'extinction totale de l'espèce..." ["genre"]=> string(30) "Action, Drame, Science-Fiction" ["homepage"]=> string(48) "http://www.tntdrama.com/shows/the-last-ship.html" ["tagline"]=> NULL ["poster"]=> string(31) "rTSuFGhBDqxvEDgzNkF2yCwBLr9.jpg" ["background"]=> string(31) "20txnfxxmpvqOdDqIiy2hO06qqG.jpg" ["episode_run_time"]=> string(2) "45" ["number_of_episodes"]=> string(2) "36" ["number_of_seasons"]=> string(1) "3" ["trailer"]=> NULL ["network"]=> string(3) "TNT" ["budget"]=> NULL ["earnings"]=> NULL ["box_office"]=> NULL ["tmdb_id"]=> string(5) "60802" ["thetvdb_id"]=> string(6) "269533" ["original_title"]=> string(13) "The Last Ship" ["original_lang"]=> string(2) "en" ["origin_country"]=> string(2) "US" ["production_company"]=> string(55) "Platinum Dunes, TNT Originals, Channel Road Productions" ["production_country"]=> NULL ["certification"]=> NULL ["status"]=> string(16) "Returning Series" ["in_production"]=> string(1) "1" ["fully_scraped"]=> string(1) "1" ["creation_date"]=> string(19) "2017-03-12 14:25:12" ["update_date"]=> string(19) "2017-03-12 14:51:11" ["series_id"]=> string(3) "179" ["all_epi"]=> string(1) "1" ["watched"]=> string(1) "1" ["percentage"]=> string(3) "100" } }
```

Comment: MySQL? That GROUP BY is invalid. Will raise an error on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), and return an unpredictable result on older MySQL versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: ok so how can I use it?

Comment: You should include sample data and desired results.

Comment: sorry but, It doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Query for ***Percentage of episodes of series watched by each user*** goes as under:

```
select uw.user_id, uw.series_id, s.title_name
    , uw_count * 100 / total_ep as percentage
from (
    select user_id, series_id, COUNT(*) as UW_COUNT
    from user_watched
    group by user_id, series_id
    ) uw
join series s on uw.series_id = s.id
join (
    select series_id, COUNT(*) as total_ep 
    from episodes
    group by series_id) t
on t.series_id = s.id
;
```

Comment: @BenfMaappy, I have edited the query and added the missing group by clause for episodes table. Now, it produces desired result.